# Display different dive when select different select option with MySQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

There are some table in my DB. In "level" table, there are 3 level, "O level", "A level" and "Another level". And I have 3 subject table for these level. They are "sub_o", "sub_a" and "sub_another" and they have different subjects. I make a select option for "level" table by SQL query.

Code is given below:

```
<select name="" id="">
    <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vhlabel");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option>".$row['label_name']."</option>"; 
    ?>
</select>
```

And there are different subject for different level. I want when I will select "O level", then its subject will be displayed in check box. And when I select another level, another subjects will be displayed in check box.

Comment: sorry; the code will be
 <select name="" id="">
  <?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vhlabel");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<option>".$row['label_name']."</option>"; 
  ?>
 </select>

Comment: add our data array too

Answer (score 0):

What you want can easily be achieved with `AJAX` and by using `jQuery` the AJAX becomes more easier. So your solution with that can somehow be as below:

```
<select name="level" id="level">
    <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vhlabel");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option>".$row['label_name']."</option>"; 
    ?>
</select>

<div id="sub">
</div>

<script>
$('#level').on('change', function() {
    var levelChangedTo = $(this).val();

    //AJAX request to some server script that will pass the changed level
    //And that script would return the HTML that would be appended 
    //to some other div which would have checkboxes.
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "serverside.php",
      data: { selectedLevel: levelChangedTo }
    })
    .done(function( response ) {
        //Here append or replace the HTML according to your needs
        jQuery('#sub').append(response);
    });

});
</script>
```

Note: This is just a guideline through which you can achieve your goal.